# spring batch customize exit description

Tags: java, spring-batch

We have a spring batch job which is executed via a method call, we are sending back exit status of job (if error occurred) using below code:

> ```
>           JobExecution jeStatus = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(je.getId());
>           String exitDescription = jeStatus.getExitStatus().getExitDescription();
>           return exitDescription;
> ```

It shows whole stack trace from propagated exception.
e.g., 
Our **ItemReader** is throwing some exception which is handled and rethrown in order to get some customized messages:

> ```
>      try {            
>           //Some code here which fails validation         
>      }catch(Exception e) {
>          throw new Exception("File validation failed");       
>      }
> ```

So what message is returned to client is:

```
> causes:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.prjItemReader' defined in class
> path resource [com/org/prjcore/config/ImportJobConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader]:
> Factory method 'prjItemReader' threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.Exception: File validation failed \r\n\tat
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(CglibAopProxy.java:687)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:637)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c6888d6d.open()\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.job"}
```

Above is a String which is also stored in job_execution_context as exit description, hence spring batch responds with the same.

I need a neat presentable message for client as ""File validation failed".

However its possible by doing string manipulations on present exit description, Is there any way to override this behavior of framework where messages could be taken out from exception instead of sending whole stack trace. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a `StepExecutionListener` for your step to do what you're looking for.

```
public class CustomStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    private static final String VALIDATION_FAILURE = "File validation failed";

    public ExitStatus afterStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        ExitStatus exitStatus = stepExecution.getExitStatus();
        String exitCode = exitStatus.getExitCode();
        if (ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode().equals(exitCode)) {
            String exitDescription = exitStatus.getExitDescription();
            if (exitDescription.contains(VALIDATION_FAILURE)) {
                return new ExitStatus(exitCode, VALIDATION_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        //no-op
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for response, how can I get reference to thrown exception. I would need stack trace not string. I am avoiding string manipulations as there could be n number of errors.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your original question. If that's the case, just use `stepExecution.getFailureExceptions()`. It will provide a list of everything thrown.

Comment: I was thinking in way I could override the method where it creates string from stack trace.But this approach is simple and better.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark the question as answered so others know it's been resolved.